# Find and replace strings in XML doc

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0, powershell-ise

I have a XML file and wanted to find all the "en-us" string within the XML doc and replace to a different culture. I am able to find them but don't know how to replace it. Tried replace, get-content and set-content and didn't work. Maybe I didn't use it correctly.

```
$testPath = "C:\temp\testing\"
$path = Get-ChildItem $testPath -Recurse
ForEach ($file in $path){
    $file | Select-String -AllMatches "en-us" | % { $_.Matches }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19794187/how-to-use-operator-replace-in-powershell-to-replace-strings-of-texts-with-sp

Comment: can you show portion of the xml?

Comment: Don't use string replacements on XML files. XML is a structured format and simple string replacements might break the structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is taken from the link in my comment.

```
$testpath = "C:\Temp\z" ;$path=gci $testpath -Recurse
$path.fullname | ForEach-Object {(GC $_ -Raw).Replace('line2','NewLine2')| Set-Content $_}
```

Comment: This will do the trick. Thanks much! @user4317867.

If you don't mind, could you explain what is the "-Raw" does? Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome!  Raw reads the entire file contents in one string and this is from `Get-Help Get-Content -full` and as it was pointed out, might break your XML file structure.

Answer (score 1):

I found this to be a quick way to replace values in text files:

```
[System.IO.File]::WriteAllText(
    'C:\path\to\export-file.xml',
    ([System.IO.File]::ReadAllText('C:\path\to\import-file.xml') -replace 'en-us', 'new value'),
    (New-Object System.Text.UTF8Encoding($false))
)
```

It will read everything in import-file.xml, replace 'en-us' with 'new value' and save to export-file.xml using UTF8 no BOM encoding. As Ansgar pointed out in a comment above though, I can't vouch that this won't break your xml.