# Out of memory exception on Informatica java transformation

Tags: java, informatica

I have written a java code which is working perfectly when I am executing locally. But gives out of memory exception when invoked from informatica. I am reading a file and splitting the contents and replacing the contents of the same file.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String delims = "#@#@#";
        StringBuilder sb=null;
        String filepath = "FILE_PATH";
        try {

            FileReader in = new FileReader(filepath);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(in);
             sb= new StringBuilder();
            sb.append(br.readLine());
            in.close();


        }
        catch (Exception ex) {

        }

        StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(sb.toString(), delims);
        try {
            FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(filepath, false);

            while (st.hasMoreElements()) {
                fw.write(st.nextToken() + System.getProperty("line.separator"));
            }
            fw.flush();
            fw.close();
        } catch (Exception ex) {

        }

    }
```

Now, the exception occurs while reading the contents of a big data file. For small data files, it is working fine.

Comment: The files are of size  say 110mb-240mb range. But the file  size can further increase

Comment: Can you use PowerCenter to load the files and modify you code to process one line at a time? When loading an entire file into memory, you will always run into OOM exception at some point.

Comment: Actually in the file there is no newline. I am trying to replace "#@#@#" delimiter with a new line. Please suggest a way we can do.

Comment: You don't need Java or PowerCenter for that. You can use sed or the string replacement feature built into Bash. http://stackoverflow.com/q/13210880/95

Comment: On Windows you have PowerShell. http://stackoverflow.com/q/19794187/95

Comment: Try increasing the Java heap size.  You will prob. need cooperation from your local Informatica admin.